# How to compute dualizing sheaf of $X \times Y$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ and $Y$ be smooth projective schemes over a field $k$. Let $\omega_X$ and $\omega_Y$ be the dualizing sheaves of $X$ and $Y$, respectively. Let $p_X$ and $p_Y$ are projection morphisms from $X\times Y$ onto $X$ and $Y$, respectively. What is the relation between $\omega_{X\times Y}$ and $p_X^*\omega_X \otimes p_Y^*\omega_Y$? If they are isomorphic, can you give a reference for proof of this?

Comment: In the smooth case, the dualizing sheaf of $X$ is just the top exterior power of $\Omega_{X/k}$. This should solve your problem completely.

Comment: I see. So $\omega_{X\times Y} \cong p_X^*\omega_X \otimes p_Y^*\omega_Y$, right?